# Does Haxe support non-reference-type compound data structures?

Tags: types, haxe, value-type

As far as I can tell, all compound data structures act as reference types and not value types, similar to object instances in Java or pointers (minus the unsafe features) in C++. Does the Haxe language have any support for user-defined compound value types, or has this been omitted to keep a clearer mapping to languages that do not have this concept (like Java)?

Comment: as far as I know, everything is by reference, most libs use some form of .copy() method to combat this when necessary